# Theoretical situation about MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I searched Google for a question I ask myself since this morning but couldn't find any information or article about it.

I was wondering, in the following situation, to improve performance (a little % still) :

**Context:** I have two column : `ID`, `AddedAt` (`AddedAt` is the Unix Timestamp of when the row is created).

Theoretically, if you insert a new row, `ID` will be +1 and `AddedAt` will be the current time.

Now, let's say it is impossible in the current situation to have two simultaneous insert, would it be better to use `AddedAt` as  a `PK` and remove the `ID` column ? `AddedAt` will be only one and unique column that does `PK` and `UNIX Timestamp`. So in the final, I will have one column instead of two.

The only bad side I see is maybe the size of the key that will be created on `AddedAt` since unix timestamp now's day is 10 digits.

Would it be better, in this situation ? What's your opinion ?

**EDIT**: What about using timestamp + ms ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timestamps are in seconds.  While you might not have simultaneous inserts, as the world tends to speed up you might get multiple inserts in a second.  Build your system to function soundly--don't use timesamps as primary keys.

Also, with statement replication sometime timestamps arent consistent across dbs... Row based replication alleviates this, but still its another reason for concern when using them.

From an good convention standpoint,  Primary Keys should have some clear meaning to others outside yourself if it's anything other than just us a plain old auto incrementing id field.  Generally, people expect numbers or char values for keys, not things like blobs, timestamps, datetimes, etc... This is especially true if later it's used for as a foreign key in another table, using  timestamp as a foreign key can be confusing to later developers.  Sure, if you have a varchar GUID field you know is unique, use it as the key. Just remember when used as a foreign key your going to eat up also quite a bit of memory if you have a huge string.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can guarantee that two events won't occur within the same 1-second interval, then sure, you could use the timestamp field as a PK.

That being said, why are you worried about key sizes? A timestamp may be 10 digits, but its internal storage requirements is only [4 bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html). By comparison, an int is also 4 bytes, so you wouldn't be losing anything - unless you're using bigints, in which case it's 8 bytes.

Also, note that timestamp fields are subject to the y2038k problem. They're essentially unix timestamps that auto-format into a human readable date for you. If your app is going to be around for more than 26 years, then you should stick with an int/bigint, which has a wraparound range of "however fast you insert rows", not a fixed date/time.

Comment: If the system is using a 64 bits integer, the y2038k problem isn't one anymore, right ?

Comment: No, because a mysql timestamp field is 4 bytes regardless of the underlying OS. The time_t stuff in the OS may be 64bit, but mysql is 4bytes and stays 4 bytes.

Comment: As I said above, int is 4 bytes, big int is 8. a timestamp is 4 bytes, regardless of the underlying OS's bit capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The primary key is not only a technical thing, it is the business representation of something that makes each object represented by a row unique.

A timestamp is a unique field of your object because you cannot (in your case) insert two objects at the same time, but it is NOT the primary definition of a business object (if you had a business object called "timestamp" then yes, the time when it was inserted should be the primary key)

An ID stands for "my client has a physical id that represents him": in the past, we would give numbers to clients on papers, bills...

Never forget that computer science is not the objective per se but the means to achieve your goals.

Comment: I like how you make a relation between business object and a simple timestamp, it's a good way to represent why an ID is better in any case. I like that. +1

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the `ID` column as the primary key as there may be scenarios in which the unix timestamp will give you a value you're not expecting.  One could be inserting very fast in succession returns the same timestamp, and another is if the server admin decides to monkey with the servers time settings.

Doing joins will probably much more obvious as people typically expect the primary key to be some sort of unique id, not a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, but performance gain will be minimal only while adding new record.
Moreover you will be forced to use timestamp for foreign_keys in all related objects.

It is worth considering only if you expect many inserts per second and a lot of records (to save storage on id column and its index), but as you said timestamp will be unique, so it's max 1 record per second :-)